# SQL Server: Text column to files with filenames from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Files 
(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL
    [FileName] [VarChar](500) NOT NULL,
    [FileXML] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
)
```

What I want is to create an XML file for every record in this table.

Filename has to be the value of FileName + '.xml', content has to be the value of FileXML.

I tried to use xp_cmdshell, but it doesn't accept varchar(max) as parameter, and the length of my XML is greater than 8000 in some cases.

I tried looking for this but I didn't really find anything.

The solution doesn't have to be fancy, it just has to work, this is a one-time action.

Comment: What is your actual question?  How do you concat two strings and store that in the `FileName` column?  Or how do you create a file?  If the latter, you should think about writing a T-SQL script and this is one situation where cursors are appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just need to know how to create the file, indeed, I didn't think about the cursor approach, I'll have a look into the file creating part again! Thanks in advance

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried to use xp_cmdshell, but it doesn't accept varchar(max) as parameter, and the length of my XML is greater than 8000 in some cases...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using SQL server integration service.Please refer below link for the tutorial.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635956/How-to-export-data-from-database-tables-to-an-XML